# Several tables with same class, only rows in first table affected, why?

Tags: jquery

I have several tables with the same class, and each has 2 rows. I want to give the td elements in each table in the second row a certain class, but the way I do it only does it for the first table, and I don't know why.

```
$('#main table.asseenin_table tr:eq(1) td').addClass('asi_second');
```

Only the td elements in the second row in the FIRST table get the class, other tables do not.

```
<table class="asseenin_table">

                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/1.jpg" /></a></td>
                    <td><a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/2.jpg" /></a></td>
                    <td><a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/3.jpg" /></a></td>
                    <td><a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/4.jpg" /></a></td>
                    <td><a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/5.jpg" /></a></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>

            <table class="asseenin_table">

                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/6.jpg" /></a></td>
                    <td><a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/7.jpg" /></a></td>
                    <td><a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/8.jpg" /></a></td>
                    <td><a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/9.jpg" /></a></td>
                    <td><a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/10.jpg" /></a></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/asseenin/thumbs/thumb.jpg" /></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

Comment: Put some HTML to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `:last-child` instead of `eq`

```
$('#main table.asseenin_table tr:first-child td').addClass('asi_second');
```

Comment: But I have 2 tr and want to target the second tr only, not the first.

Comment: this works, thanks, but what if I had 3 tr and wanted to target the second one? Is there a way to target the SECOND, or THIRD etc. specifically?

Comment: Try using nth-child(2n) or nth-child(3n) etc

Answer (score 1):

As documentation at http://api.jquery.com/eq/ says: `Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.` So after `:eq(1)` you only have one elements.

To solve your problem use `:nth-child()` (http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
$('#main table.asseenin_table tr:nth-child(1) td').addClass('asi_second');
```

Comment: But how do I target the SECOND tr only, not the first?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe like this: (change "#" for this "." - ofcourse add class to table and remove id)

```
$('.main table.asseenin_table tr:eq(1) td').addClass('asi_second');
```

Comment: That still selects the first tr. `tr:eq(1)` is reducing result to exactly one element.